# Get length of 2-D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I just need a clear answer about this, if anyone knows.
I have already **checked similar questions**, but none of them clarify what happens in a multi-dimensional array. So,

```
typedef u_char block[16];
block *array = (block*) somePointer;
```

I'm trying to read a stream of **bytes** as an array of blocks.
Again, every element has size of exactly 1 byte, so don't try to confuse me even more, with sizes and elements.
I assume (hope) that the variable `array` has became an array of blocks.

```
array[n][16];
```

How can i determine the value of `n`?? Is it finite?

Some testing showed that:

```
sizeof(array) == 4;        // n != sizeof (array)
sizeof(*array) == 16;        // n != sizeof (*array)
```

Comment: `sizeof(pointer) == 4` (32bit, you're on), and `sizeof (char[16]) == 16`...why am I not surprised?

Comment: "I assume (hope) that the variable array has became an array of blocks." - If a pointer was an array, it would not be called "pointer", but "array"! It does not even point to a 2D array. Please learn these fundamentals. There are enough questions here about how to declare a 2D array (note: it is **not** something like `int **array;` - that is another missconception of beginners!

Comment: And **never ever** cast if 1) it is not necessary or 2) you don't understand **all** implications or 3) don't accept them all!

Comment: "How can i determine the value of `n`?" - `n`!

Comment: `I assume (hope) that the variable array has became an array of blocks.`... arrays are ___NOT___ pointers and vice-versa.

Comment: So I get it, `n` can be as large as you intend to read, as clarified below. Thank you all for your helpful comments and answers.

Comment: Have a look at [`fread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) ... the text and also the example section.

Comment: ^ I want to vote you up, but I dont think I can. Thank you anyway.

Comment: The allowed range of `n` depends on what `somePointer` is pointing to.

Comment: ^ It points to a stream of captured network bytes, which after the payload, seem to continue with random bytes... infinitely. That was my original intent, to know if there is an end to it!

Answer (score 1):

**TL/DR Version**

You will not be able to calculate `n` in a single expression using the `array` variable.  A pointer to `T` only points to a single instance of `T`; it has no way of knowing whether that instance is the first element of an array of `T` or not.

**Long Version**

Given the declarations

```
typedef u_char block[16];
block *array = (block*) somePointer;
```

Then the following are true:

```
   Expression        Type           
   ----------        ----           
        array        block * == u_char (*)[16]  // pointer to 16-element array of u_char
       *array        block   == u_char [16]     
 sizeof array        size_t  == sizeof (block *) == sizeof (u_char (*)[16]) == 4 // on your system                   
sizeof *array        size_t  == sizeof (block)   == sizeof (u_char [16])    == 16
```

Assuming a declaration like

```
block someArray[10];
```

then `someArray` is a 10x16 array of `u_char`.  You can determine the number of rows in `someArray` via

```
sizeof someArray / sizeof *someArray
```

This divides the total number of bytes in `someArray` (160) by the number of bytes in a single row of `someArray` (16), giving you the number of rows (10).

However, if you write

```
block *array = someArray;
```

then you *will not* be able to determine the number of rows in `someArray` using the `array` variable.  `sizeof array` returns the size of the pointer, not the thing being pointed to, and `sizeof *array` returns the size of a 16-element array of `u_char`, not the size of `someArray`.

So when you wrote

```
block *array = (block*) somePointer; // what is the type of somePointer,
                                     // and is the cast really necessary?
```

you set `array` to point to a *single* instance of `block`.  You cannot determine from the pointer itself how many rows of `block` are in `somePointer`.

You could use a sentinel value (similar to the 0 terminator in strings) to mark the last row somehow (such as if all elements of that row are set to 0 or 255 or some other pattern):

```
#define TERMINATOR 255
...
bool lastRow( block *b )
{
  bool result = true;
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof *b; i++ )
    result = result && (b[i] == TERMINATOR);
  return result;
}

int main( void )
{
  ...
  block *array = (block *) somePointer;
  ...
  size_t count = 0;
  while ( !lastRow( array++ ) )
    count++;
  ...
}
```

Of course, this only works if a row of all 255 (or 0, or some other value) is not otherwise valid data.  Otherwise, you need to keep track of the size of `somePointer` manually.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. `somePointer` is `u_char*`. This points to a stream of **bytes** through network capture. The length of that data, I understand already, depends on what you are looking for (and capture length, of course).

Answer (score 0):

That's the size of the pointer to the `array`. It points to the first element of the array:

```
sizeof(array) == 4;
```

That is the size of the array to which `array` points to, i.e. the first element (which is a an array of length 16):

```
sizeof(*array) == 16;
```

`n` has to be finite. There are no infinite arrays in C.
The value of `n` must be defined prior use.

Comment: In general, you're correct, but I don't see how this can be considered an answer of the question. :)

Comment: **How can i determine the value of n?? Is it finite?** Can you find the answers to these questions in my answer?